# Proper guidelines to understand and work on Facebook API, Twitter API etc

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, twitter, google-api

I want to create and work on various API for Facebook, Twitter etc. e.g. Create an APP for Facebook, host it on my website using facebook customized login button, like button etc...

I need to understand all required basics for working much like a Facebook or Twitter or Google developers.

I'm with an Electrical Engg background and for me it's hard to understand these concept by directly going through their respective developer sites. Because those sites have codes of various languages which is difficult for me to understand. So I'm planning to first clear basics required and then work on API.

Can somebody please suggest some step-wise guidelines so that I can go ahead with firm knowledge of basics required. (I have coding knowledge in C, C++, Java and Python. Though at intermediate level, not expert.)

I thought of asking here on SO, because perfect coders can only guide me perfectly.

Thanks.

Comment: one such example I got is at [Guide for absolute beginners](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1607)

Answer (score 0):

This course is short and to the point, give it a try:
http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/apis

Comment: Thanks. But, do I need to learn something from `Web Fundamentals`, `PHP`, `JavaScript`, `Ruby`, `HTML` etc. before going through those `Apps with API`?

Comment: One thing at a time, don't stress yourself, you should have some basic knowledge in HTTP communications, a little about client side scripting, and it won't harm you to try playing with one server side scripting language like PHP or Python (You don't need them all).

API's are more of a way of dealing with data, sending and receiving, it's a concept and not a strict language. So I'd suggest reading a little about Web Fundamentals and then try out some of those APIs.
P.S. most APIs return data in the form of JSON or XML format, read a little bit about the structure of those too.